# The controller for path '/BingSiteAuth.xml' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seo

I just launched a site a few weeks ago, and I've been getting several of these errors recently.

What does this mean, is Bing trying to crawl my site? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file will simply help Bing with your site.

First, go to: https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/SubmitSitePage.aspx and add your site.

You'll then be prompted to download the `BingSiteAuth.xml` file. Add that somewhere in your mvc project (probably the root folder) and then, in `Global.asax.cs` in the `RegisterRoutes` method, add:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("BingSiteAuth.xml")
```

If you choose to add the file somewhere other than the site root, make sure you map a route to it that looks like it's at the root with:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("bingsiteauth",
                    "BingSiteAuth.xml",
                    "~/mysubfolder/BingSiteAuth.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the BingSiteAuth.xml to the root of your site.

Fairly certain this is like submitting your sitemap.xml to Google Webmaster Tools.